# Java - list indexed by text

Tags: java

I am looking a way yo storage array like this:

```
array['name'] or array.add('name','value').
```

arrayList doesnt work like that.
What's the best  way to storage values like that?

Comment: its java, neither c# nor ruby, you can only pass index :)

Comment: You don't want a list, you want a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: @ay89 you apparently dont know C# or ruby.

Comment: @texasbruce may be, but justifying it is out of context here.

Comment: Just to clarify, in ruby( and C# if I remembered correctly), indexed array and associated array are 2 different types, just like Java. In JavaScript and PHP they are the same

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). A [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a good choice:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

// to add name/value pairs - like your array.add('name','value')
map.put("name", "value");

// to retrieve values - like your array['name']
map.get("name");
```

Comment: If you care about insertion order too, then use a `java.util.LinkedHashMap` instead of the vanilla `HashMap`. In general, I advocate the linked variety for any case where the slight increase in memory used per key-value pair is not a problem... the ordered iteration pays dividends in output and debugging.